# Magento 2: Preference is not working

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.3.1, preference

I want to override `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` using preference to modify the `_buildClearSelect($select = null)` method.

For this, I have created **`di.xml`** with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
</config>
```

and **`Collection.php`**

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\Product;

class Collection extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
{
    /**
     * Build clear select
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DB\Select
     */
    protected function _buildClearSelect($select = null)
    {
        $select = parent::_buildClearSelect($select);
        $select->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);
        return $select;
    }
}
```

Above code is not working. I have already tried to flush cache and remove the code directory from the generated directory.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: kindly use     public function __construct() function and let me know if any issue

Comment: Hi @mohith! I have tried this but no success.

Comment: hey @SanchitGupta did you figure it out? I'm facing similar issue with some other Protected Method Override

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency  to your etc/module.xml

```
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
```

and clear cache and generated/code/

Happy coding

Comment: Hi lazy_coder! it is already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency to your etc/module.xml

```
   <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Backend" />
    </sequence>
```

Comment: Hello Mohith! Can you please explain why we add Magento_Backend?

Comment: Its working right!!!

Comment: No, it's not working.